# Spring MVC 3.0 Basic Authentication Implementation

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently transforming my Web Application tn Java with Spring MVC framework from ASP.NET (good way to learn it though -:) ) I need to implement authentication in my application: Please tell me if my approach is good and professional enough and if not what is the best practice to do that:

First of all I'm writing User class which holds all information about current user firstname/lastname/email/id/etc....

```
class User implements Serializable{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long id;
private String email;

///Settters and Getters

}
```

I'm implementing class Named DlSession and implementing it on sesison level.

```
<bean id="MySession" class="DlSession" scope="session">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>

class DlSession implements Serializable{
private User currentUser;

public DlSession(){}

// getters and setters:
}
```

When User submits his user/pass I'm verifying the credential and if user exists retrieving all the user Data to the instance of User class. Then I'm setting currentUser in Session to b the user I retrieved:

```
mySesison.setCurrentUser(user);
```

In order to verify authentication I need to check:

```
if (mySession.getcurrentUser() == null)
//return unauthenticated 
else 
//return authenticated
```

To logout user from system I just doing:

```
mySession.setcurrentUser(null);
```

Is this approach correct? any suggestions are more then welcomed. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are already using **SpringMVC**, why don't you use also [**SpringSecurity**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/) ([manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html))?
It has all the components built-in that you need to set up your [form-based- or basic-authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic). And, you can easily add new authentication methods in the future.

**EDIT**: see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4067736/74694) for a possible solution, using Spring Security.